# Access table cells data in php

Tags: php, database, mysqli, insert

I can't seem to really find a way around this problem.

I have a file named validateLogin.php as follows:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <title>Login Validation</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS Files/indexstyle.css" />

    </head>

    <body>
            <div id="middle" align="center">


                <?php

                    if ( isset($_POST["phone"]) )
                    {   
                        $phone=($_POST['phone']);

                        include "connect.php";  
                        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE phone='".$phone."'");

                        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
                        {
                            if (!isset($_SESSION))
                            session_start();

                            $phone=($_POST['phone']);


                            $_SESSION['phone']=$phone;
                            $_SESSION['timeout']=time();

                            if ($stmt=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT m.sname,m.size,m.price from sandwich s inner join menu m where s.sname=m.sname "))
                            {

                                $stmt->execute();

                                $stmt->bind_result($col1,$col2,$col3);

                                echo'<form name="form" action = "orderUpdate.php" method="POST">
                                        <center>
                                            <table border cellpadding=3>
                                        <tr> 
                                            <th style="background-color: #FFFF00;"> Sandwich Name </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: #FFFF00;"> Size </th>
                                            <th style="background-color: #FFFF00;"> Price </th>
                                        </tr>';
                                         $count1=1;         
                                 while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                                    echo '
                                                        <tr border="1px solid black" >
                                                            <td border="1px solid black" width="30%" id="col1" name="col1">'.$col1.'</td>
                                                            <td border="1px solid black" width="10%" id="col2" name="col2">'.$col2.'</td>
                                                            <td border="1px solid black" width="20%" id="col3" name="col3">'.$col3.'</td>
                                                            <td><input type="radio" name="sandwich" value="'.$count1.'"></td>       
                                                        </tr>
                                                    ';
                                $count1=$count1+1;              
                                }
                                echo '<tr> <td> <input type="submit" value="submit"/> </td></tr>';
                                echo'</form>';

                            }                       
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            echo '<script type="text/javascript">

                                alert("Sorry. Customer does not exist.");

                                window.location.href="index.php";

                            </script>';
                        }
                    }

    ?>

            </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Now from the output that is generated in the table form, a user will select a particular radio button that associates a row. I need to insert this data into my mysql database table. I am however not sure how to access the appropriate col1, col2 and col3 that needs to be inserted using based on the users selection.

Schema

```
customer 
(
phone char(10) primary key,
building_num int,
street varchar(20),
apartment varchar(20)
);


sandwich 
(
sname varchar(20) primary key,
description varchar (100)
);


menu 
(
sname varchar(20),
size varchar (20),
price decimal(4,2),
primary key (sname, size),
foreign key (sname) references sandwich(sname)
);


orders 
(
phone char(10),
sname varchar(20),
size varchar(20),
o_time datetime,
quantity int,
status varchar(10),
primary key (phone, sname, size, o_time),
foreign key (phone) references customer(phone),
foreign key (sname, size) references menu(sname, size)
)
```

Comment: So you want to update the data, based on which field the user selects? Can you clarify what the user will be trying to do?

Comment: ok so he puts in his phone number and a list of sandwiches with their name, size and price is retrieved from the database, consider like a menu. he selects 1 of these with a radio button and then hits the submit button to order that paricular size. so basically his order needs to get stored in the database. Does this help you?

Comment: Do your tables have a primary key? (can you post your table schema?)

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

Your problem has to do with this line:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="sandwich" value="'.$count1.'"></td>
```

You should change `$count1` to the variable that contains the sandwich name. For reasons described below, you shouldn't do this (but it'll probably work, as long as you treat the strings appropriately).

This field will become `$_POST['sandwich']` and will have whatever value was selected.

```
$sname = $_POST['sandwich'];
$query = "INSERT INTO orders (sname, ...) VALUES ('{$sname}', ...)";
```

(of course, you should be using prepared statements and sanitizing the input appropriately).

**Long Answer**
 - Your table syntax is all over the place. You can't have the same `id` for multiple elements, there is no `name` attribute for `<td>`, and `<th>` should be nested inside `<thead>`, not a `<tr>`. I've updated it to give the cells a *class* name instead, which will let you apply consistent styling with CSS (instead of ugly inline statements), and access the data conveniently through javascript if you ever need to do so.

- I'm not entirely sure what's going on with this query:

> ```
> SELECT m.sname,m.size,m.price 
> FROM sandwich s 
>     INNER JOIN menu m 
>     WHERE s.sname = m.sname
> ```

But it looks like your problem stems from lack of a unique identifier for each sandwich. The names are okay, but typically it's preferable to use a unique ID to associate with each sandwich. Use mysql's [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) to generate this automatically.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sandwiches ( 
> sid int(5) not null auto_increment,
> primary key(sid), 
> sname varchar(255)....
> ```

This way, you can pass the ID as a form value and positively associate each record with that ID. It looks like it's what you're trying to do with `$counter1`, but it just takes that extra step out.

```
<input type="radio" name="sandwich_id" value="<?=$sid;?>" id="sid_<?=$id;?>">
<label for="<?=$sid;?>"><?=$sandwich_name;?></label>
```

Once all those radio buttons are selected, you'd do something like:

```
<?php
$sid = (int)$_POST['sandwich_id'];
$phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/",'', $_POST['phone']; // Strips all non-numeric chars out
$query = "INSERT INTO orders (sandwich_id, customers_phone) VALUES ({$sid}, '{$phone}')";
```

Of course, you should use the prepared statements - that's just an example. By inserting the sandwich ID in the orders table, you can `JOIN` to the sandwiches table to generate receipts or order screens.

Comment: can i not do it anyway without a sid. the sql query is to only map the sname from the sandwich to the menu table, to retrieve the size and price that's it. I'm still gonna try implementing what you suggested, but without a sid